# Is there a way to ungroup grouped images within the PowerPoint slide using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-pptx, powerpoint-2007

Is there a way to ungroup grouped images within the PowerPoint slide using Python?
Or is there a way that I can make such a function on my own?

Testing through powerpoint 2007 version. Thank you.

I would like to inquire after confirming that the python-pptx module does not have the above function.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't figured a way of doing so without damaging the XML but if you are OK with clicking repair once you open the PowerPoint file this does the trick...

```
import pptx
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.enum.shapes import MSO_SHAPE_TYPE    

presentation = Presentation("GROUP.pptx")

for slide in presentation.slides:
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        if shape.shape_type == MSO_SHAPE_TYPE.GROUP:
            group = shape.element
            parent = group.getparent()
            index = parent.index(group)
            for member in group:
                parent.insert(index, member)
                index += 1
            parent.remove(group)
            
presentation.save("UNGROUP.pptx")
```